# Стоит ли показывать заказчику тестовый сайт?

Tags: веб-программирование

Всем здравствуйте!
Я фрилансер и занимаюсь Front end разработкой сайтов. У меня есть тестовый сайт где я тестирую верстку. Как Вы думаете, стоит ли заказчику давать ссылку на тестовый сайт чтобы он посмотрел на верстку до оплаты или лучше после оплаты? Какова вероятность того, он сворует всю верстку от туда и не заплатит за работу? А вы бы стали давать ссылку в моём случае?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Работай сначала через биржи фрилансеров( или как они там называются). Там есть безопасные сделки. Никто никого не обманет. А потом вотрешься в доверие клиенту или наоборот, и будут платить без проблем. У меня есть несколько заказчиков, которые смотрят работу и платят сразу на вебмани без лишних комиссий. Все дело в доверии. Иначе никак.

Comment: А Вы сталкивались когда-нибудь с тем, что Вас кидал заказчик?

Comment: Согласен, риск сводится к минимальному. Но все таки есть. Бывают "Отказники", это люди которые получили все что хотели и будут пытаться всячески прервать Сделку без риска. 

Такие персонажи после завершения работы, начинают цепляться к мелочам, просить переделать кучу всего. Нужно сделать беккап по окончанию работы, и дополнительные правки лучше делать в новом каталоге. Делайте правки, но если они по мелочи и не противоречат первичному заданию и ТЗ. Если вы начинаете замечать, что правки не существенные (например поменять места для 27 разных блоков, на 1 писель) - обратитесь в арбитраж.

Answer (score 4):

Хм, я вижу тут несколько вариантов:

1. Показывать картинку верстки
2. Показать видео верстки (отображение в хроме, мозиле, опере, ИЕ, и других браузерах)
3. Сделать css файл максимально не читаемым - название стилей к примеру 32 произвольных букв и цифр, добавлено в стиль кучу других произвольных стилей, которые к верстке не имеют отношения, в итоге воровство такой верстки будет достаточно трудозатратна (чтобы переименовать эти бесмыслицы в нормальный текст)
4. Дать собственную программу-браузер, который бы делал особый запрос на сайт при котором и подключались эти стили. Естественно код просматривать запретить. Например в Delphi, C# есть стандартные компоненты WebBrowsers основанные на IE движке.

Comment: 1,2,3 - полумеры
4 - хороший вариант

Comment: 4 — это адовая жесть, а не вариант. Ну какой мало-мальски соображающий человек будет ставить неподписанное приложение, чтобы посмотреть на верстку?

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать это да, это как крайняя мера, да и продемонстрировать на различных браузерах не получиться. Мне больше нравится метод (3)

Comment: Можно на яндекс народ положить, там антивиром проверяет.

Comment: @IVsevolod Лично я придерживаюсь мысли, что не надо [даже пытаться ничего защищать](http://goo.gl/Cb1j4) — те, кто захотят, все равно при желании смогут своровать. Правильнее не заставлять платить тех, кто не хочет, а концентрироваться на тех, кто хочет:

> You're going to find that there will be some that will simply steal your code and reuse it. Don't worry too much about them as they weren't going to be paying customers anyway. Instead, make it easy for your own customers to buy and use your stuff. Make sure you provide support; that's where the real value is going to come from.

Answer (score 3):

Я сталкивался 2-3 раза, точно не помню.Потом наблюдал свою верстку на готовом проекте, обидно.
Но показывать верстку надо, без этого не как.
Я стал работать так, либо безопасная сделка, либо 50% предоплаты.

Comment: А как Вы думаете может ли заказчик своровать верстку с тестового сайта когда получит ссылку?

Answer (score 3):

Программно запрети выделение, запрети клик правой кнопкой мыши, запрети все хоткеи (сохранение файла, копирование текста, просмотр кода и так далее). На вход на страницу поставь капчу (причем лучшим вариантом будет пустая страница с капчей, и контент который грузится через ajax при правильной капче).

Как итог, вручную не своровать, программным образом не своровать. Возможно есть плагины для браузеров позволяющие сохранять страницу, могу порекомендовать вставить java который крашит страницу при не соответсии доменов.

Comment: Расскажите, пожалуйста, как запретить `Ctrl-Shift-J` в `Google Chrome.`

Comment: Когда-то давно читал про это статью на хабре, там было довольно подробное описание проблемы. Сейчас поищу, но как вариант ловить по jquery хоткеи и закрывать вкладку с тестовым сайтом. Ведь добросовестный клиент не будет лесть в бэкенд, а попросит - пусть платит.

Comment: если есть отображение, то своровать исходники можно, как ни запрещай доступ, дело лишь во времени возни ) Например поставить какой-нибудь прокси, все что пройдет через него сохраниться, соответственно все исходники сохраняться )

Comment: Я не отрицаю, что взломать можно. Но это будет целая вечность агонии.
Капча от программ защитит, а невозможность редактировать код от ручного похищения.

Comment: @HappyCougar Proxy все решает ) понимаете, через него как раз пройдут все исходники. Так же дело 15-и минут создать свою программку, которая без проблем перехватит исходники

Comment: view-source: site.ru никто не отменял.

Comment: Какая агония? Где? Alt -> Меню «Инструменты» -> Веб-разработка -> Инспектор в Файрфоксе не заблокировать никак. Наверняка то же самое в Chrome и даже в IE.